# How to apply a custom function to a variable in PyMC?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

At one step in the model I'm writing, i have to calculate the error function of a quantity. What I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
from math import erf
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm

sig = pm.Exponential('sig', beta=0.1, size=10)
x = erf(sig ** 2)
```

This fails because `erf` doesn't work on arrays. I tried:

```
@pm.deterministic
def x(sig=sig):
    return [erf(s) for s in sig]
```

but with no success, I know it's possible to get the result with:

```
np_erf = np.vectorize(erf)
x = np_erf((sig ** 2).value)
```

but this doesn't seem like the correct way because it doesn't produce a `pm.Deterministic` but just a `np.array`. How can I do it instead? (PyMC is version 2.3)

---

**Edit:** The above examples were simplified for clarity, here's the what the relevant passages look in the real code. Ideally, I would like this to work:

```
mu = pm.LinearCombination('mu', [...], [...])
sig2 = pm.exp(mu) ** 2
f = 1 / (pm.sqrt(np.pi * sig2 / 2.0) * erf(W / sig2))
```

but if fails with the message `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. Going the `np.vectorize` route

```
np_erf = np.vectorize(erf)
f = 1 / (pm.sqrt(np.pi * sig2 / 2.0) * np_erf(W / sig2))
```

crashes with the same error message. The list comprehension

```
@pm.deterministic
def f(sig2=sig2):
    return [1 / (pm.sqrt(np.pi * s / 2.0) * erf(W / s)) for s in sig2]
```

works as such, but leads to an error later in the code at this spot:

```
@pm.observed(plot=True)
def y(value=df['dist'], sig2=sig2, f=f):
    return (np.log(np.exp(-(value ** 2) / 2.0 / sig2) * f)).sum()
```

and the error is `AttributeError: log`.

I've got the calculation of the error function working using a numerical approximation, which should mean that the general setup is correct. It would be just nicer and clearer to use the `erf` function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't realize that if you create a variable using the `pymc.deterministic` decorator, the parameters passed to the function are `numpy.array`, and not `pymc.Distribution`. And this allows to `numpy.vectorize` the function and apply it to the variable. So instead of

```
sig = pm.Exponential('sig', beta=0.1, size=10)
x = erf(sig ** 2)
```

you need to use

```
sig = pm.Exponential('sig', beta=0.1, size=10)
np_erf = np_vectorize(erf)

@pm.deterministic
def x(sig=sig):
    return np_erf(sig ** 2)
```

and it works.

Comment: Aha! Glad you got it figured out. The former works with some simple functions, but not all.